# Implementation of IntentService using LinkedBlockingQueue?

Tags: android

I'm trying to download multiple files using IntentService. The IntentService donwloads them okey as expected one at a time, the only problem is that when the Internet is down the intent service will not stop the donwload rather it will get stuck on the current thread. If I manage to stop the current thread it will continue running the other threads stored in its queue even though the internet connection is down.

It was suggested in another post that I use LinkedBlockingQueue and create my own Worker thread that constantly checks this queue for new threads. Now I know there are some increased overheads and thus performance issues when creating and destroying threads but that's not a concern in my case.

At this point, All I want to do is understand how IntentService works which as of yet I don't (and I have looked at the code) and then come up with my own implementation for it using LinkedBlockingQueue controlled by a Worker thread. Has anyone done this before ? Could provide a working example, if you feel uncomfortable providing the source code, pseudo code is fine by me. Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I eventually implemented my own Intent Service using a thread that has a looper which checks the queue which in turn stores the intents passed from the startService(intent).

```
public class MyIntentService extends Service {



    private BlockingQueue<Download> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Download>();


    public MyIntentService(){
        super();
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();

        new Thread(queueController).start();

        Log.e("onCreate","onCreate is running again");


    }



    boolean killed = false;
    Runnable queueController = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          while (true) {
            try {
              Download d =queue.take();

              if (killed) {
                 break;
              }
              else {
                d.downloadFile();
                Log.e("QueueInfo","queue size: " + queue.size());
              }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
              break;
            }

          }
          Log.e("queueController", "queueController has finished processing");
          Log.e("QueueInfo","queue size: " + queue.toString());
        }
      };

      class Download {
            String name;
            //Download files process
            void downloadFile() { 
                   //Download code here
             }

                Log.e("Download","Download being processed is: " + name);
            }
            public void setName(String n){
                name = n;
            }
            public String getName(){
                return name;
            }
       }




    public void killService(){
        killed = true;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            Download d = new Download();
        d.setName(intent.getStringExtra("VIDEOS"));
        queue.add(d);
      return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("stopSelf","stopSelf has been just called to stop the Service");
        stopSelf();     
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


}
```

I'm not so sure about the START_NOT_STICKY in the onStartCommand() method. If it's the right flag to return or not. Any clarification on that would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm thinking, instead of downloading all these files one by one, i'm thinking of zipping them and then download the zip file once and then when download is completed extract the files in the sd card, is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I eventually implemented my own Intent Service using a thread that has a looper which checks the queue which in turn stores the intents passed from the startService(intent).

public class MyIntentService extends Service {

```
private BlockingQueue<Download> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Download>();


public MyIntentService(){
    super();
}



@Override
public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();

    new Thread(queueController).start();

    Log.e("onCreate","onCreate is running again");


}



boolean killed = false;
Runnable queueController = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      while (true) {
        try {
          Download d =queue.take();

          if (killed) {
             break;
          }
          else {
            d.downloadFile();
            Log.e("QueueInfo","queue size: " + queue.size());
          }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
          break;
        }

      }
      Log.e("queueController", "queueController has finished processing");
      Log.e("QueueInfo","queue size: " + queue.toString());
    }
  };

  class Download {
        String name;
        //Download files process
        void downloadFile() { 
               //Download code here
         }

            Log.e("Download","Download being processed is: " + name);
        }
        public void setName(String n){
            name = n;
        }
```